# PDE using separation of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Use the method of separation of variables to solve the equation
$\frac{∂w}{∂t} −\frac{∂^2w}{∂x^2}= 0, 0 ≤ x ≤ π,$
subject to the conditions
$w(x, 0) = 0, w_x(0, t) = −1, w_x(π, t) = −1.$

Would I be right in saying that the BCs are inhomogeneous and I would have to transform the original equation? I tried this but am struggling to get an answer in the form of a series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{%
> \begin{array}{l}
> \ds{\partiald{\mrm{w}\pars{x,t}}{t} - \partiald[2]{\mrm{w}\pars{x,t}}{x} = 0}
> \\[2mm]
> \ds{x \in \pars{0,\pi}}
> \end{array}\,,\qquad\qquad
> \left\{\begin{array}{rclcl}
> \ds{\mrm{w}\pars{x,0}} & \ds{=} & \ds{0}&&
> \\[3mm]
> \ds{\left.\partiald{\mrm{w}\pars{x,t}}{x}\right\vert_{\ x\ =\ 0}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\left.\partiald{\mrm{w}\pars{x,t}}{x}\right\vert_{\ x\ =\ \pi}} & = &\ds{-1}
> \end{array}\right.}$

\begin{align}
&\partiald{\mrm{w}\pars{x,t}}{x} =
-1 + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\mrm{A}_{n}\pars{t}\sin\pars{nx}
\\
&\mrm{w}\pars{x,t} =
\mrm{f}\pars{t} - x -
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\mrm{A}_{n}\pars{t} \over n}\,\cos\pars{nx}
\\
&0 = \dot{\mrm{f}}\pars{t}  -
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n}\bracks{\dot{\mrm{A}}_{n} + n^{2}\,\mrm{A}_{n}\pars{t}}\,\cos\pars{nx}
\\
&\mrm{f}\pars{t} = a = \mbox{constant}\,,\qquad
\mrm{A}_{n}\pars{t} = A_{n}\pars{0}\expo{-n^{2}t}
\end{align}

---

$$
\bbx{\ds{\mrm{w}\pars{x,t} =
a - x -
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\mrm{A}_{n}\pars{0} \over n}\,\cos\pars{nx}
\expo{-n^{2}t}}}
$$

---

$$
0 = \mrm{w}\pars{x,0} =
a - x -
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\mrm{A}_{n}\pars{0} \over n}\,\cos\pars{nx}
$$

---

$$
0 = \int_{0}^{\pi}\bracks{%
a - x -
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\mrm{A}_{n}\pars{0} \over n}\,\cos\pars{nx}}\dd x 
\implies a = {\pi \over 2}
$$

---

$$
0 = \int_{0}^{\pi}\bracks{%
{\pi \over 2} - x - \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}
{\mrm{A}_{m}\pars{0} \over m}\,\cos\pars{mx}}\cos\pars{nx}\,\dd x 
$$

---

$$
0 = {1 - \pars{-1}^{n} \over n^{2}} - {\pi \over 2}\,
{\mrm{A}_{n}\pars{0} \over n} \implies
{\mrm{A}_{n}\pars{0} \over n} =
{1 - \pars{-1}^{n} \over n^{2}}\,{2 \over \pi}
$$

---

$$\bbox[#ffe,15px,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{%
\mrm{w}\pars{x,t} =
{\pi \over 2} - x - {4 \over \pi}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}x} \over \pars{2n + 1}^{2}}\,
\expo{-\pars{2n + 1}^{2}t}}}
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, It has helped me understand the question more but is it possible to solve it by the method of separation of variables?

Comment: @ross Thanks. $\mathrm{A}_{n}\left(t\right)\cos\left(nx\right)$ at the very beginning is equivalent to 'variable separation'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would be right. Look for a (simple) function $\phi(x)$ satisfying the boundary conditions and define a new unknown $u$ as $u(x,t)=w(x,t)-\phi(x)$.

Comment: So would I be correct in using $w(x,t)=u(x,t)+x$?

Comment: Yes, that is the simplest choice for $\phi$.